# How to prevent filtering results via Twitter Bootstrap's Typehead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I am using typehead with ajax for autocomplete. When making a search i am facing with unwanted filters.

For Example when I search for "Back to the Future" It's okey.

But when i search for "Future Back" I'm expecting too see ->
"Back to the Future"

```
 $('.ajax-typeahead').typeahead({

    source: function (query, process) { 
        return $.post('http://www.ilanlarnette.net/autocomplete/lokasyon', { lokasyon: query }, function (data) {
            objects = [];
            map = {};
            $.each(data, function(i, object) {
            map[object.label] = object;
            objects.push(object.label);
            });
            return process(objects);
        });
    },
    items: 15,

    updater: function (item) {
        alert("selected "+item+" "+map[item].id+" "+map[item].mahalle+" "+map[item].ilce);
    }
});
```

Working Example Can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FER3F/2/)

Even it's in the search result set. Results are not showing in [typehead](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead)s dropdown menu.

Comment: Can you post YOUR code please?

Comment: Have a look at the `matcher` option: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

Comment: `return process(objects);` should just be `process(objects);`  You can't return a value from an AJAX callback.

Comment: @Mr.Web working jsfiddle added to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I type `future` in your jsfiddle example I see back-end related error, I think you should fix that first.

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined variable: lokasyon_arrays</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/autocomplete.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 34</p>

</div>null
```

Just like *Rocket Hazmat* said you need to implement custom matcher for your typeahead so it would look something like this.

```
yourInput.typeahead({
    source: yourSource,
    matcher: function(item) {
        // The 'item' parameter is any item in your list (e.g. "Pizza" )
        // Use this.query to access the search string (e.g. "I want a Pizza")
        // return true if this.query matches item through your custom logic
    }
});
```

Comment: @motto You have error on your server-side if you type more than 3 characters. `Message:  Undefined variable: lokasyon_arrays`. I think you should start by fixing your back-end error. Edit: It sometimes occurs and sometimes not.

Comment: may be it's temporary because of upload. no problem for me now. could you try again ?

Comment: @motto I still see error when I type `future` or `back`. It is impossible to test with this error. :(

Comment: ah okey i noticed that. It's actually because of back to the future is not in actual table. I have added it just because of making example simpler. It should be working now without any problem. Can you test it again ?